# C++ type id at compile time

Tags: c++, hash, compile-time, typeid

I want to generate a hash for a class based on its derived type at compile time. Today I generate it like:

```
template<class Type>
class TypeBase 
{
public:
    static const unsigned s_kID;
};

template<class Type>
const unsigned TypeBase<Type>::s_kID = hash(typeid(Type));
```

but this generates (pretty unnecessarily) run time initialization code (the hash(..) function does a simple hash based on std::type_info::name() )

Ideas ?

Comment: Isn't there a risk that you get hash collisions or maybe that's not a problem?

Comment: @Andreas: When creating the hashes, I also have a map with the hash entries. Thus I can check if there are collisions. Besides that, the number of classes is maybe 20, so I guess I'm safe with that too.

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like `id = ++someGlobalCounter`? (I realize this isn't petformance critical, just curious)

Comment: @Andreas: The class is used in IPC communication, and I'm not sure that a global counter would ensure that both communicating parties are "synced" (i.e. having the same id for the same type). With a hash it is guaranteed (as long as you use the same C++ compiler for both applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given everything else that happens at process startup, and how simple and elegant your existing code is, assuming you don't hash a gazillion types, I'd leave your existing solution exactly as it is.

Comment: Thanks. Case of premature optimization, eh ? ;)

Comment: Indeed. As long as you don't have any runtime impact like users that are complaining that the application is taking 150 microseconds too long to startup, leave it as is. And don't try to do any magic of casting the pointer of that variable to unsigned, as this is not going to be portable.

Comment: @robert yes, it would seem to me to be that.

Comment: Now I find myself in a situation once again needing non-RTTI type information for creating an ID, simply because I want to strip my executable of RTTI symbols :)

Comment: What about calculating the hash from the address of the resulting type_info object? That should be even cheaper and even unique, or not?

Comment: @TilmanVogel yes, that's an idea worth investigating, but it would possibly be unique also for every execution of the application, depending on where it is loaded, which would render it useless for IPC , but for internal communication it would probably be fine.